# why we link LDAP Directory to Relaying Party (mod_auth_opendic)?

Tags: spring-ldap, mod-auth-openidc

When we look to OpenidConnect flows, your solution does not match with.

It's to The identity provider should make this EndUser Authentication with LDAP Directory , not the Relaying Party. "mod_auth_openidc" play the role of a Relaying Party not an Identity Provider.

Can you please tell me what do you think ?

[Apache2 Reverse Proxy with authentication over OpenID Connect and authorization over ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40802680/apache2-reverse-proxy-with-authentication-over-openid-connect-and-authorization)

Answer (score 0):

The use case is that the Relying Party may choose to apply authorization rules based on locally stored data such as application roles to grant permission to protected resources to a user who was authenticated against a 3rd-party Identity Provider.